# Adding files as if they were added at first time?

Tags: git

I'm facing a situation which should not have happened had I did it correctly at first place.

Anyway , I've created a `master` branch which contains a root commit.
Then I've created many branches that  were created from that master  `master` branch.

[image]

So each branch in here ^ was created by :

- checkout `master`
- create a branch

All folders are in the same root folder(file system).

But now I see that I've forgotten the `.gitignore` file.

I've added it to the `master` branch.
 But apparently it only holds to the master branch. If I checkout another branch , I still see the -should-be-ignored files.
But apparently it doesn't work since the checkout branch doesn't have the `.gitignore` file

Which makes me walk through manually  at every branch and add the `.gitignore` file.

**Question**

Since all branches were created from `master` , Is there any way to add the `.gitignore` file to the `master` branch and cause the other branches to   "re-inherit" `master`'s  files again ?

(so that every branch will have the `.gitignore` files , as if it was there at first place ?

Comment: `.gitignore` logic is not dependent on branches, but on the repo config itself. Branches *should* share this setting... have you tested the same file from different branches with `git check-ignore -v <path>`? (Also be sure to execute both parts of the test from the same directory, not to introduce other differences.)

Comment: @RomainValeri How should it suppose to work ? There was no gitignore file at the beginning. Then I've created many branches. and on each branch i've created projects.  many of the files were unnecessary to be added to the git. so i've added a gitignore file ,  and then i commited it to the master branch. but when I've swapped to another branch , that gitignore isn't exists , and then I saw many unnecessary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is clearer now from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332624/adding-files-as-if-they-were-added-at-first-time?noredirect=1#comment97393359_55332624).

> There was no gitignore file at the beginning. Then I've created many branches. and on each branch i've created projects. many of the files were unnecessary to be added to the git. so i've added a gitignore file , and then i commited it to the master branch. but when I've swapped to another branch , that gitignore isn't exists , and then I saw many unnecessary files.

Your .gitignore isn't taken into account on your branches, because you created it on `master` and did not merge this addition in the branches themselves. So when you switch to another branch, you don't have a `.gitignore` any more.

Either merge `master` into your branches (I guess it won't be very convenient in some cases) or just cherry-pick the relevant commit everywhere, but you effectively need your branches to *have* the .gitignore present to be active.